# Salesforce Execute Composite Request Delete Records

Tags: salesforce, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Not sure this should go to connectors or data-weave , but posting it here.  This is related to salesforce-composite-request connector.
First I need to get a list of Ids and then delete them , is it possible using composite-request . Here is what I'm trying with dw:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
{
    allOrNone: true,
    compositeRequest: [
{
        method: "GET",
        referenceId: "GetOrderIds",
        url: "/services/data/v48.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id++From+OrderItem+WHERE+Order.SAP_Sales_Document_Number__c+=+'70022247'" 
    },
    {
        method: "DELETE",
        referenceId: "deleteOrderIds",
        url: "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/OrderItem/Id/" ++  "@{GetOrderIds.records.Id}"
    }]
}
```

With above the error is: **Invalid reference specified. No value for GetOrderIds.records.Id found in GetOrderIds** .

Its working when i use @{GetOrderIds.records[0].Id} but it's deleting only one record , i need to delete all the list.

Any Idea ?

Comment: The reference notation (the one with @) is from the Salesforce composite API so it has nothing to do with Dataweave. I found that you can call DELETE with a set of ids separated by comma, but I'm not sure if it's possible to reference it from a previous call. I didn't found any example referencing a collection. I would go with 2 separate calls just for now and maybe create a Salesforce ticket for assistance to clarify if it's posible.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I switched to making 2 calls to Salesforce one for Get and another for Delete.

Comment: It's an old thread and I'm not an expert, just on the learning mode. Can't we loop through the GetOrderIds array and construct the DELETE body? Just a thought, again I'm no expert in this area.